# How to retrieve $_POST variable from jquery serializearray()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, serialization

I have a problem in retrieving the $_POST data from jquery `serializeArray();`. I tried to `for` loop the $_POST to get the data but failed.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
    function update_cart(){
    var fields = $(':input').serializeArray();
    console.log(fields);
    var url = "update_cart.php";
    $.post(url, {fields:fields}, function(data) {
         alert(data);
    }, "html");
        return false;
}
```

In my PHP code :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The result is this:

```
array(1) {["fields"]=> string(15) "[object Object]"}
```

So, can anyone please teach me how to access the $_POST data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to nest your serialized object; that seems to be what's causing the error. Just set your post call to:

```
$.post(url, fields, function(data) {
     alert(data);
     }, "html");
```

That should work; you might also want to change from using `serializeArray` to using `serialize`.

Once this is properly configured, if you have:

`<input name="foo" value="bar" />`

It can be accessed as:

```
 $_POST["foo"]; //bar
```

Comment: hey yahelc..Thank for your fast reply! I am able to access the $_POST data already! Thanks!